# Buildfire: Social Wall Plugin Modification

Tags: buildfire

Is it possible to disable the Wall notifications on Buildfire on the Social Wall plugin or default the user to not follow the group? I've tried setting "receivePushNotification" to false with no luck. I would paste the code here, but there's nearly a thousand lines. I'm looking at the widget.wall.controller.js file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To be clear you tried setting [receivePushNotification] to false?  https://github.com/BuildFire/socialPlugin/blob/9d71c5a2608921dd336c68390237aa5ed874b3a0/widget/controllers/widget.wall.controller.js#L560

Comment: @Daniel_Madain, correct I did try that as well as tried setting [followNotification] to false as well. https://github.com/BuildFire/socialPlugin/blob/9d71c5a2608921dd336c68390237aa5ed874b3a0/widget/controllers/widget.wall.controller.js#L552

Comment: Thats what is used to unsubscribe manually. Thats odd. I believe there is a closed Premium version of the Social wall that has that feature configurable. It may be worth contacting your Account Manager to see if your account has access to it and if not if its worth the purchase

Comment: @Daniel_Madain thank you. I'm requesting access now, I appreciate it.